# Why do these Villagers and other mobs want to keep climbing a nearby mountain?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a village near a mountain. For some reason villagers, golems and animals want to climb that mountain.

What possible reason could there be?

[image]

Comment: I heard rumors that pathfinding prefers higher blocks, but don't know why. It definitely seems true, I have seen 4 endermen cram onto 1 enderchest multiple times.

Comment: [To hug the mountain. To envelop… that mountain. They want to make love to the mountain.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HU2ftCitvyQ)

Comment: Well, I dont want to be in their way then @ChrisBouchard

Answer (score 18):

The fact that there's cobblestone and a flat dirt formation makes me think that the village is embedded or otherwise a part of the mountain. I believe the single water block, that appears to be all by itself in the bottom left corner of the picture, is a classic symptom of a village attempting to place a farm or other structure on a slope.

All this said, it's possible that there are villager workstations, such as a composter by farmland, that the villagers are attempting to reach.

Comment: There are also wheat tiles near the water

Answer (score 16):

There was a [video by YouTuber WhiteSzoneJazz](https://youtu.be/jpi50LX2Qyk?si=zqweLDHJGqRThCQx) a while ago that investigated this - the main observation is the following (watch the video for the full explanation):
Mobs will randomly pick a solid block in a cuboid centered around the block they're standing on. In the column of that chosen block, they will then look upwards for the first non-solid block, and they will try to pathfind towards that.

If you now count the number of blocks that will lead them to move upwards/downwards, it turns out that there is roughly a 4x larger chance for them to move upwards (depending on the exact terrain shape), since there are more pathfinding-targets in the uphill direction.

Answer (score 2):

Villagers (and most other mobs, especially breeding mobs) **love**, I mean absloutely **love** space. They will try to gain the most space possible. As the top of the mountain is flat, and with more space (more than the few block flat area on the mountain) they will naturally try to find space, climbing up. This is also why ground villagers will not climb mountains, even when a mountain is nearby.

Comment: How is "more space" measured? Least amount of mobs per area? Per volume? Least amount of blocks per area/volume? Highest amount of blocks to stand on per volume? None of these seem plausible. Also how does "flat" equal "the most space possible"? And what leads you to believe that the mountain top will be flat to begin with? And what does your last sentence mean? What are "ground villagers"? Are they _not_ trying to "gain the most space possible"? Do they have different data IDs compared to non-"ground villagers"?

Comment: @Siguza as in like blocks - Space = blocks of flat ground (platforms)